# python code - split a path with special delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, path

We have a column in a dataframe in the format of a path delimited by a backslash then space.
I am trying to decompose the path into single components (columns) making the path.

I tried to use os library which didn't work!

One way to do it, is also to use a lambda like this:

> df[['level1','level2','level3',...,leveln]] = df.Path.apply(lambda x:
> pd.Series(str(x).split("\ ")))

but here again the line is hardcoded because I need to know how many levels are in the path, and if we want to use the code for different scenarios, doesn't look practical to everytime identify and hardcode the path levels #.

Comment: how are you creating the dataframe? you could use Pathlib instead

Answer (score -1):

Let's use pathlib and pandas in combination, assuming we have a directory called `tmp` and 3 files.

[image]

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd 

files = Path('home/umarh/tmp').glob('*')

df = pd.DataFrame({'files' : files})

print(df)

   files
0  /home/umarh/tmp/file1.txt
1  /home/umarh/tmp/file2.txt
2  /home/umarh/tmp/file3.txt
```

Although `files` looks like a string, it's actually a Pathlib object

```
df['files'].apply(type)

0    <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>
1    <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>
2    <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>
Name: files, dtype: object
```

---

This makes grabbing the `parts` easy, I'll use the last two parts of my string for readability, but this will return a tuple:

```
df['parts'] = df['files'].apply(lambda x : x.parts[-2:])


   files                                parts
0  /home/umarh/tmp/file1.txt  (tmp, file1.txt)
1  /home/umarh/tmp/file2.txt  (tmp, file2.txt)
2  /home/umarh/tmp/file3.txt  (tmp, file3.txt)
```

Comment: Yes thanks for the detailed explanat. Since the input of the code is a spreadsheet, and the path column needed to be decomposed, I used the same line of code but added how many levels I want to decompose which made it more generic and reusable across other spreadhseet : for instance if I need 3 first decomposed path elt df[['level1','level2','level3']] = df.Path.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split("\ ",3)))

Comment: @Tortuga_C ah that makes sense, can you provide a sample of your data in the post (doesn't have to be the same) and i'll show you how you can turn the string in a pathlib object to work with.